# How to prevent Vagrant from creating a hostonly network?

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

When creating a (linux) virtual machine using Vagrant and VirtualBox, vagrant implicitly creates a hostonly network interface on the virtual machine.

Can this be prevented? I think there are no vagrant options to do this. Am I right?
What is the best generic/OS-independent way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you not want that interface or do you want a different interface?

Comment: I do not want that interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of preventing creating the host-only network, because that's how Vagrant was designed to work (see [Virtual Machine](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/virtualbox/boxes.html#virtual-machine) requirements in the "Creating a base box" chapter).

It's the way Vagrant communicates with the machine: injects an SSH keys, checks the status, runs provisioners, etc.

Likewise, the guest machine's first network interface will be dedicated to the communication with Vagrant.

Without it Vagrant becomes unusable; instead you can just run your own virtual machine in VirtualBox.